# what is the difference between using var and not using it when declaring variable?

Tags: pine-script

I can declare a variable without using var

```
int test_var = 5
```

I can also declare using `var` keyword.

```
var int test_var = 5
```

What is the difference between the 2 different methods? If there is no difference, then why have `var` in the first place?

I am using pinescript v5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the var keyword is used, the variable is only initilized once, on the first bar if the declaration is in the global scope, or the first time the local block is executed if the declaration is inside a local block. After that, it will preserve its last value on successive bars, until we reassign a new value to it.

If you don't use the Var keyword the value will be reset on each new bar.

[You can read more about it here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Variable_declarations.html#var)

Below code example shows a variable without Var keyword, notice the value is always either 1 or - 1 since it gets reset to 0 every bar. The second picture is the same code but with the Var keyword. Notice it doesn't reset every bar

[image: No Var]

Same code using Var keyword
[image: Same code but using Var]

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. 
Will using `var` result in better performance since the variable is initialised only once? Is it fair to say using `var` is a good practice to follow?

Comment: Depends on what you are using it for. For example if you are taking a recent swing high and only want to change the value if a higher high is made then yes, however if you are just taking the high of every bar then you wouldn't need to.

Comment: No performance hit in using `var` even if it's not helpful, right?

Comment: @user3848207 there is a slight performance penalty when using `var`. Therefore it is not recommended to use it for constant variable declarations etc.